# How can I calculate the interest over an amount of money using a for loop in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

When I try to calculate the interest over an amount of money put in, my script keeps calculating the interest over the starting balance. I'm trying to constantly calculate the percentage of interest over the new amount of money, using a for loop.

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
var startBalance = document.getElementById('input1');
var percentage = document.getElementById('input2');
var output = document.getElementById('result');

btn.onclick = showBalance;

function showBalance() {
  var interest = (startBalance.value / 100) * percentage.value;
  var newBalance = +startBalance.value + interest;
  var resultaat = "";

  for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    resultaat += "Year " + i + ": €";
    resultaat += newBalance.toFixed(2) + "<br>";
    newBalance += interest;
  }

  output.innerHTML = resultaat;
}
```

```html
Starting balance: <input type="text" id="input1">€ <br><br> Percentage of interest: <input type="text" id="input2">% <br><br>

<button id="btn">Calculate balance</button>

<p>New balances for the next few years:</p>
<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: Here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/mqod8hc3/ (also not really a programming problem per se, more a math issue)

Answer (score 0):

just redefining interest with **newBalance** as variable will solve your problem

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
 interest = (newBalance / 100) * percentage.value
 resultaat += "Year " + i + ": €";
 resultaat += newBalance.toFixed(2) + "<br>";
 newBalance += interest;
}
```